# How to create a serverless VPC with paid billing account while the free trial is active?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine

I just created my GCP project, and I have already inputted my billing account.
On the top of my page, I dont see any [free trial status](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/free-cloud-features#how-to-upgrade) for me to upgrade it anymore. So I assume that my billing should have been upgraded to the paid billing.

When I check on my billing account, there is my linked project, when I open the linked project, it is showing the remaining free trial credits. But it also shows a disclaimer that start from Dec 2, 2023 I will receive an incurring charge. So I still assume that my billing account should really have been upgraded.

But when I'm trying to create a `Serverless Vpc Connector`, it keeps showing an error like below.

> Operation failed: Insufficient CPU quota in region

How should I fix this?

Comment: VPC connectors require an instance that consumes from your CPU quota. What is your CPU quota and how many are being used? You can request a quota increase. The `Edit quotas` links is on the IAM & Admin -> Quotas page (top right). However, not all quota increase requests are approved.

Comment: @JohnHanley Hi, I just checked my Quotas under the IAM & Admin page, it's weird, I can't find my CPU quotas at all. In the Compute Engine API services, I find a lot of quotas including firewall, Networks, and others. But none is for CPU quotas. How can I add that quota?

Comment: It is there. Filter on `CPU`. The `Filter` is located right above the list of quotas. If it is actually missing, you will need to contact Google Cloud Support (paid) or maybe Google Cloud Billing support (free). If you just created the project, perhaps you have to wait 24 hours for everything to populate.

Comment: @JohnHanley after I filter on `CPU`, it shows a lot of lists, and as I check, all of the CPU limit is 0, and the `current usage percentage` is also 0%. how can I increase it? And which `CPU` should I increase the quota? it is okay for me to pay also

Comment: Do you have billing enabled? Did you have a billing problem? If your quota is zero, check other regions. The only way to increase it is to request a quota increase (select one and click the edit quota link).

Comment: @JohnHanley yes my billing was activated yesterday. All my quotas were 0 for CPU under all regions. But when I check now, it become 8. And the usage is still 0%. I tried to create my serverless VPC again, but still showing the same error. So, my last option now is to contact the sales team?

Comment: Which quota is now 8? You need quota in the location you are creating the VPC connector. Quotas are requested via the web interface. If you are a business, you can talk to the sales team but it is the billing team that approves quota requests.

Comment: @JohnHanley the quota for `CPU` in the `region:Southeastasia2' which I was trying to create the VPC. Ok, I will try to contact google team for this. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, the default to create the Serverless VPC access is having the minimum of 2 instances and maximum of 10 instances. While the default limit for the `CPU` is only 8. So reducing the maximum instance for the Serverless VPC would result in successfully creating the Serverless VPC access.

In another word, you cannot use the default setting to create the serverless vpc access.

Comment: Interesting. I had not noticed that before. The GUI should have a little box saying the maximum available quota is 8. I would not want to consume all of my remaining CPU quota on one connector, which probably only needs one CPU.

Comment: @JohnHanley yes it's rather confusing. After I successfully created the connector, my `CPU` usage is based on the minimum instances. But when I created it, it checked the maximum instances instead. it's kinda misleading.